# BVLinearGradient was not found in the UIManager?

Tags: react-native, gradient

There is documentation about this, but it is for macOs only. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient.

**I linked the library by running `npm install react-native link react-native-linear-gradient`.**

**I don't understand this i dont have a ios folder, i installed pod but my ios folder remained empty:**

iOS
For React Native >= 0.60.0 run the following command in the ios/ folder and skip the rest of the section.

pod install
CocoaPods
Add the following line to your Podfile:

pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
or:

**This below is only for macOs ?**

Manually
Open your project in Xcode, right click on Libraries and click Add Files to "Your Project Name" Look under node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/ios and add BVLinearGradient.xcodeproj. (Screenshot 1) (Screenshot 2).
Add libBVLinearGradient.a to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries (Screenshot 1) (Screenshot 2).
Click on BVLinearGradient.xcodeproj in Libraries and go the Build Settings tab. Double click the text to the right of Header Search Paths and verify that it has $(SRCROOT)/../react-native/React - if it isn't, then add it. This is so Xcode is able to find the headers that the BVLinearGradient source files are referring to by pointing to the header files installed within the react-native node_modules directory. (Screenshot).

**How to do it in Windows and i don't have an ios map inside node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/?**

how can I make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check whether these two lines are in your 'package file'.

> 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
>
> 'BVLinearGradient', :path =>
> '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

If yes then --

> Run "pod install" under $project path/ios before react-native run-ios.

Comment: 'pod install' did it for me!

Comment: 'pod install' worked here for me also.

Comment: I don't have an ios folder or a pod file and my app still runs fine on ios but I cannot install the linear gradient package. What do I do?

Answer (score 47):

use this one if you are using **expo**

1 . paste this in terminal window :

```
expo install expo-linear-gradient
```

2.add the import statement to the file :

```
import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient';
```

worked for me !

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks!, Also I have to uninstall react-native-linear-gradient.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue with Android.
**Solution**: Kill the app and relaunch this should solve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I noticed the same thing, if you have the app running and install something using npm you have to restart (ctrl+c then npm run android / ios) to get the dependencies to work.

Answer (score 2):

Easy Way..! Try This..!

1. Run this code in Terminal window

   expo install expo-linear-gradient
2. Use this code to import the LinearGradient

   import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

Answer (score 2):

- Step 1 - npm install expo-linear-gradient
- Step 2 - import { LinearGradient } from expo-linear-gradient

Answer (score 2):

Simple use a expo command.

- npm install expo-linear-gradient

Use this on the page

- import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

Answer (score 1):

Simply you just need to go to ios folder

```
cd ios
pod install
```

That's it

Comment: In the accepted answer: `Run "pod install" under $project path/ios before react-native run-ios` Isn't this basically the same solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, install the https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient library.

then go to the cd ios and run

```
cd ios
pod install
```

now use go back using cd ..

and run (optional )

```
 react-native link react-native-linear-gradient
```

now run

```
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using windows & react-native cli (not expo):

**1-** in **android/settings.gradle**, check if

include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')

exist .. if not, add them

---

**2-** in **android/app/build.gradle**, check if

```
implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
```

exists in dependecies{ ... } .. if not, add it

---

**3-** in **android/app/src/main/java/com/{YOUR_APP_NAME}/MainApplication.java** , find

@Override
protected List getPackages() { ....}

Then replace the comment **// packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());**

with =>
**packages.add(new LinearGradientPackage());**

Comment: At Step 3
The Better Way is to add 

import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage; 

in MainApplication.Java and leave 

packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage()) as it is.
The above line will automatically add the all the packages imported , instead of explicitly adding them yourself.

Comment: you're right .. I'll try it next time

Comment: It didn't help me, but here, I found the solution: https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#other

Answer (score 1):

### Android

If you are on android, simply do the native rebuild again with:

```
yarn android
```

or

```
npm run android
```

Answer (score 1):

For Expo users, running `npx expo prebuild` fixed it for me. And make sure you rebuild your app again. Here's the prebuild commands based on your platform:

#### IOS:

```
npx expo prebuild --platform ios && npx expo run:ios
```

#### Android:

```
npx expo prebuild --platform android && npx expo run:android
```

Answer (score 1):

jz an additional info for those android user:

1. clean ur gradle: `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
2. reinstall ur node modules: `cd .. && rm -rf node_modules && npm i`
3. start again with fresh cache: `npm start -- --reset-cache`

for me theese step fixed this issue

[reference](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#ios-build-fails-library-not-found-bvlineargradient-was-not-found-in-the-uimanager)

Answer (score 0):

If using expo and this error is thrown after installing react-native-linear-gradient follow along.

**error ?** the expo framework still does not have "sight" of the linear gradient package .

**solution ?**  Run the command "expo install expo-linear-gradient" from your root folder, go to the file that you had previously imported the linear gradient as "import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient" and change the line to "import {LinerGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient'".

Restart your server, "expo start".
PS: This solution is only applicable for react-native projects being built using expo

Answer (score 0):

- cd iOS
- bundle install
- bundle exec pod install

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the package from expo if you are running an expo build!

I experienced similar issue because I was migrating from a React-Native managed app to an expo build, so the `react-native-linear-gradient` package from React-Native didn't work even after killing and restarting the app. It turned out I had to use the  `expo-linear-gradient` package instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error as soon as I added the  component to a view.

To get rid of the error, I went to the `/ios` folder and ran `pod install`.  As indicated in the [README of the package](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#ios-build-fails-library-not-found-bvlineargradient-was-not-found-in-the-uimanager).

If your pod install does not work, ensure that cacaopods is installed and that you have the last ruby version.